# Allow .php on one Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have pretty URLs enabled, and I don't want to change the functionality of article reading, but I have a requirement that a particular (in-house) file be allowed legacy linking, and so I need to make Wordpress respect the .php at the end of this particular file.  I also need to maintain the query string parameters passed through from the legacy referrer, like:

```
wordpresssite.com/foo.php?this=that&why=becauseISaidSo
```

I suspect there is some htaccess tweaking that will allow this to work, but I don't know what to change to fix this without breaking something else.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the top of your `.htaccess` (i.e. **before** the custom WordPress rewrites):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L,QSA]
```

It essentially prevents the rewriting of any file that exists (such as `foo.php`). Using `L` flag, we tell Apache to stop rewriting if there's a match. By also using the `QSA` flag, the GET variables will also be preserved and exposed for `foo.php` to use.

Comment: Additionally consider this with a method to just create a legacy directory, where php and html is served up as if wordpress didn't exist, like mysite.com/legacy/

Comment: @BenM, while I can now get to this page and not have the URL rewritten, I'm still getting a 404.

Comment: @tremor, the client requires the very specific url from a previous incarnation of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Just below `RewirteEngine On` line in WP .htaccess file add this line:

```
RewriteRule ^foo\.php$ - [L,NC]
```